# NFS mount in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, nfs

Does anybody have any experience mounting nfs on win xp?
I know that it works on Win 7 (and it is a new feature).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download [Windows Services for UNIX Version 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=274) to support NFS mounts.

From @Sridhar-Sarnobat:  The simplest way to get up and running is:

1. Copy your `/etc/passwd` (and /etc/group) files from your NFS server to your Windows XP client and point to them in User Name Mapping -> Configuration subtab.
2. In the User Name Mapping -> Maps subtab, check **Simple Maps**, select **Show User Maps**, and associate your main XP user account with your main Linux user account.
3. Click **Apply**
4. Browse your newly accessible NFS network shares by going to My Network Places -> Entire Network -> NFS Network -> Default LAN -> (IP address or name of server)

If your password gets rejected but you've got the user mapping correct, you need to ensure that the target resource has the right permissions for that Linux user.

Comment: Have you any hands on experience with that? Is it reliable enough? Or I might be better off migrating to Win 7?

Comment: I've not used it, but what's included in Windows 7 is a just newer Version of Services for Unix

Comment: It is reliable enough from my experience. Though after doing a fresh install of Ubuntu I can't remember how I got it to work :(

Comment: Update: I finally got it working. Don't be discouraged if the above steps I added sound complicated. It's perfectly logical even if its a bit of clicking around to set up.

Comment: The link to Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX is broken.

Comment: The above link is no longer valid. And I have been unable to NFS mount an exported directory on to the Windows machine, The client exist with a success, makes an entry into /etc/mnt, but the mount doesn't really happen.

Any pointers to what I can do?